# BeautifulSoup: how to ignore spurious end tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've read many good things about BeautifulSoup, that's why I'm trying to use it currently to scrape a set of websites with badly formed HTML.

Unfortunately, there's one feature of BeautifulSoup that pretty much is a showstopper currently:

It seems that when BeautifulSoup encounters a closing tag (in my case `</p>`) that was never opened, it decides to end the document instead.
Also, the `find` method seems to not search the contents behind the (self-induced) `</html>` tag in this case. This means that when the block I'm interested in happens to be behind a spurious closing tag, I can't access the contents.

Is there a way I can configure BeautifulSoup to ignore unmatched closing tags rather than closing the document when they are encountered?

Comment: Given the behaviour, I presume you're using `html5lib`. The HTML spec says that a `</p>` with no `p` element on the stack opens a new one, so what you're seeing here is what the standard says and what all browsers do.

Comment: I had similar behavior, where an erroneous `</span>` closing tag was truncating a table (`page.find('table')` was only returning the part of the table up to the erroneous tag), using "html.parser". Both lxml and html5lib processed it successfully, so we went with lxml since it's faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BeautifulSoup doesn't do any *parsing*, it uses the output of a dedicated parser (`lxml` or `html.parser` or `html5lib`).

Pick a different parser if the one you are using right now doesn't handle broken HTML quite the way you want it to. `lxml` is the faster parser and can handle broken HTML quite well, `html5lib` comes closest to how your browser would parse broken HTML but is a lot slower.

Also see [*Installing a parser*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) in the BeautifulSoup documentation, as well as the [*Differences between parsers* section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

Comment: html.parser broke on an extraneous closing tag within the element I was searching for, truncating the output at the extra tag; once I found your answer and changed my parser, I found both other parsers handled it more gracefully. Thanks for the tip on relative speeds, and it's good to know that html5lib's output most closely resembles a browser's behavior in case we run into something that trips up lxml in the future!